# C++ create empty byte

Tags: c++, qt

I was wondering if you could help me with a small problem I have:

I am currently devloping in C++/Qt and got the following error message:

```
P:\Produkt\Savor_V100\webapi.cpp:84: error: C2664: 'CryptoPP::PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction::DeriveKey' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'byte *'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

The parameter in the function is not used, therefore I would like to pass an empty byte in there. After a bit of research I found out that a byte is just a simple unsigned char?

My code looks like this:

```
byte* unused;
qDebug() << CryptoPP::PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction::DeriveKey(CryptoPP::SHA1::StaticAlgorithmName(), CryptoPP::SHA1::BLOCKSIZE,  unused, user->getPassword(), sizeof(user->getPassword()), user->getSerial(), sizeof(user->getSerial()), 0 );
```

Comment: you can pass `0`, or `nullptr` since the argument type is `byte *`. Or try `reinterpret_cast<byte*>(CryptoPP::SHA1::StaticAlgorithmName())`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comment, the issue here is with the first argument of the function, not with the third where you used `unused`. Since I guess you do need this parameter, you should try as suggested:

```
qDebug() << CryptoPP::PasswordBasedKeyDerivationFunction::DeriveKey(
              reinterpret_cast<byte*>(CryptoPP::SHA1::StaticAlgorithmName()),
              CryptoPP::SHA1::BLOCKSIZE,
              0,
              user->getPassword(),
              sizeof(user->getPassword()), 
              user->getSerial(), 
              sizeof(user->getSerial()), 
              0 );
```